# Find key using lambda expression in HttpContext.Current.Items cache

Tags: c#, lambda, httprequest

I have a cache by request, implemented using HttpContext.Current.Items like this:

```
private static readonly Lazy<CacheCurrentCall> lazy =
    new Lazy<CacheCurrentCall>(() => new CacheCurrentCall());

public static CacheCurrentCall Instance
{
    get
    {
        IDictionary items = HttpContext.Current.Items;
        if (!items.Contains("CacheCurrentCall"))
        {
            items["CacheCurrentCall"] = new CacheCurrentCall();
        }
        return items["CacheCurrentCall"] as CacheCurrentCall;
    }
}

private CacheCurrentCall()
{

}

public void Add<T>(T o, string key, int cacheDurationSeconds = 0)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(key, o);
}

public void Clear(string key)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(key);
}

public bool Exists(string key)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Items[key] != null;
}

public bool Get<T>(string key, out T value)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Exists(key))
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }
        value = (T)HttpContext.Current.Items[key];
    }
    catch
    {
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now I would need to remove all of the keys starting by a particular string, and therefore I was thinking of a method like this

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetKey (Func<string, bool> condition)
```

and then looping through the results and clear them (I could even clear directly in a Clear acepting a lambda expression, I guess). But I'm lost trying to implement such a method, if it's possible actually.

Any help?

Thanks

Edit:

Servy, I was trying (have been blindly trying some things but more or less following this path)

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetKeys(Func<string, bool> condition)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach (var key in HttpContext.Current.Items.Keys)
    {
        if (condition(key as string))
        {
            list.Add(key as string);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

But I'm getting:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I'm gonna try right now p.s.w.g that besides it probably works it's much more elegant to my eyes.

Second edit:

I needed to change slightly p.s.w.g solution. I don't store strings in the cache but other kind of objects, so I use this now

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetKeys (Func<string, bool> condition)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Items
        .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
        .Where(e => e.Key is string && condition(e.Key as string))
        .Select(e => e.Key as string);
}
```

And a call to clear the cache is for example this one

```
public void ClearCache()
{
    var ownedItemSummaryKeys = CacheCurrentCall.Instance.GetKeys(k => k.Contains("OwnedItemSummaryCurrent"));

    foreach (var ownedItemSummaryKey in ownedItemSummaryKeys.ToList())
    {
        CacheCurrentCall.Instance.Clear(ownedItemSummaryKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What problems have you had implementing this solution yourself?  Are you getting an error, incorrect output, or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) property is an `IDictionary`, so you'd have to do this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetKey (Func<string, bool> condition)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Items
        .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
        .Where(e => e.Key is string && 
                    e.Value is string && 
                    condition(e.Key as string))
        .Select(e => e.Value as string);
}
```

or in query syntax:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetKey (Func<string, bool> condition)
{
    return
        from e in HttpContext.Current.Items.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
        where e.Key is string && 
              e.Value is string && 
              condition(e.Key as string)
        select e.Value as string;
}
```

---

**Update** I miss-read the question. I thought you wanted to select *values* based on certain a criteria of the keys. If you want to select just the keys, it's actually a bit easier:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetKey (Func<string, bool> condition)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Items.Keys
        .OfType<string>()
        .Where(condition);
}
```

Or in query syntax:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetKey (Func<string, bool> condition)
{
    return
        from k in HttpContext.Current.Items.Keys.OfType<string>()
        where condition(k)
        select k;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I eventually needed to do a small change (the question wasn't that clear, my fault) to your code (see second edit) but it works.

Comment: @mitomed Sorry I misunderstood your question at first. See my updated answer for a better solution.